# Regular Expression returns empty resulat

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to extract something from a text for example in this text:

`r_w + [DPTPSRMX] < psrmmn_w und B_zepsrpl`

I want to extract the content of `[]` in this example:DPTPSRMX

I wrote this code in vba:

```
Dim regklammer As New RegExp
Dim regdcm As New RegExp

Dim matchgklammer As MatchCollection
Dim matchgdcm As MatchCollection

regklammer.Pattern = "\[+\w*\]"
regklammer.Global = True

regdcm.Pattern = "\w*"
'regdcm.Global = True

Set matchgklammer = regklammer.Execute(Pruefhinweis.Value)

For K = 0 To matchgklammer.Count - 1
 MsgBox matchgklammer.Item(K)
  Set matchgdcm = regdcm.Execute(Trim(matchgklammer.Item(K)))
  MsgBox matchgdcm.Item(0)
Next K
```

but matchdcm.count is 4 and it returns 3 white spaces +`DPTPSRMX`. Could you please say me, why my code findes white spaces and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to either learn about match groups or lookaround, applying two different patterns can have all sorts of special outcomes **especially** if your pattern can match empty strings (`\w*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for you is to simply remove the first and last character from `matchgklammer.Item(K)` using normal string operations (`substring`) instead of a regular expression. You know that the first and last characters in each match is `[`and `]`.

Another way, if you want to use regular expressions to do it, is to add a [matching group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
regklammer.Pattern = "\[(+\w*\)]"
```

And then:

```
For K = 0 To matchgklammer.Count - 1
 MsgBox matchgklammer.item(K).groups(0)
Next K
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried to use matching group in VBA access but I got this error:`method execute of object iregexp2 failed vba` does it possible to use matching group in vba?

Comment: I actually don't know. I haven't used VBA in years and I've never used regexp in VBA. The example should work in VB.Net, though.

Answer (score 1):

the `*` character in a regex matches zero or more of the preceding pattern.  Try usin `+` instead to match 1 or more.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx